# Full HD LCD on windows 8.1 is too bright and too sharp

Tags: windows-8.1, lcd

I got a new notebook with Windows 8.1 and 1080P monitor.

It's too bright and the picture is too sharp in comparison to my old notebook's 1366x768 screen, even if I turn off all the brightness.

I get eye strain, is there any setting to adjust it?

Comment: Too sharp? As in “the content is too small”? What size is the screen?

Comment: @DanielB I made the font larger, but fonts are so crispy and sharp and White is so White... 

And colors are so Colorful, It's hard to explain ....

Comment: Could you perhaps take a photo (not a screenshot!) of your screen?

Comment: Did you try to change the color-temperature setting in the monitor itself (it is NOT a Windows settings)? Most monitors come pre-set for a very high value which makes white/grey a glaring blue-white. Try lowering it. It should make all colours "warmer" and less "bright/glaring".

Comment: @Tonny Actually, I did this and it became normal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay at the native resolution of Full HD (1920 * 1080), but [change the DPI scaling to 125% or 150%](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28310-dpi-scaling-size-change-displays-windows-8-1-a.html) in the control panel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have done this ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean your resolution is too small to see comfortably, the best way to change this is to **adjust your resolution** in display options.

Follow the instructions on the following link to change your resolution, try setting it to **1280x720** (assuming its currently set to 1920x1080, the 1080p standard), this should make it less sharp, play around with the resolution slider until you find something you're comfortable with.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/change-screen-resolution

As far as brightness, other than the in built options on the screen, there is now way (I know of) to lower the brightness any further, though it should dim slightly through use during its lifetime.

Comment: It's a 15.6 in with 1920 * 1080 resolution.
Can I make it 1366 * 768 without damaging my LCD in a long time..

Comment: You won’t damage anything, but it’s a waste of resolution.

Comment: @Daniel B Not necessarily, the best resolution to use is the one you're most comfortable with.

Comment: @YetiFiasco I believe otherwise—native is always best. What matters is how much content is squeezed into how much “real world” space. The most prominent application of this principle are Apple’s “Retina” displays.

Comment: The point I'm making is, if you can't read the display, it's not much use.

Answer (score 0):

I installed f. Lux and it adjusts the setting to 6100k and everything became normal.

https://justgetflux.com/